# Inserting multiple rows from multiple question radio form in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, radio-button, multiple-insert

I have a form to determine the user's personality. So each question (there are 25) has 4 possible answers to choose from:

```html
<form method="post">

  <div>
    <label for="name"></label>
    <input name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
  </div>

  <div>
    <label for="surname"></label>
    <input name="surname" id="surname" placeholder="Surname">
  </div>

  <br>

  <div>
    <label for="q1">Question 1</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="S"> q1c1 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="D"> q1c2 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="K"> q1c3 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q1" id="q1" value="I"> q1c4 <br>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div>
    <label for="q2">Question 2</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="D"> q2c1 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="K"> q2c2 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="I"> q2c3 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q2" id="q2" value="S"> q2c4 <br>
  </div>

  <br>

  <div>
    <label for="q3">Question 3</label><br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="S"> q3c1 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="I"> q3c2 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="D"> q3c3 <br>
    <input type="radio" name="q3" id="q3" value="K"> q3c4 <br>
  </div>

<br><br>
  <button>Submit</button>

</form>
```

I need to insert the name, surname, and the selection of the question in one line. The next row in the database should also contain the name, surname, and then the next question's selection for all 25 questions.

My table `users` in the database only has 3 columns namely: `name`, `surname`, `q`

I am very new to PHP and tried some previous questions but none worked for my particular scenario.

Comment: Start from doing that of just a single person. NEVER do more than one task at a time.

Comment: besides, your database structure is wrong. answers should go into different table

Comment: Yes, I get that. This is the initial step, next would be to separate the user info and answer in different tables and add another table with IDs to link them together.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are working fully with PHP, so no JavaScript or Ajax involved.

first of all you need to specify where your request should send:

```
<form method="post" action="https://example.org/target.php">
```

in `target.php`, you need to read data out of `$_POST`. In your case, it must be something like `$_POST['name']`.

From there on, you can do whatever you want with the data.

Please consider this answer as a minimal question as you need to do further checks, such as security checks, prevent SQL injections and overall data validation.